# Как выводить лог бота в консоль в Python с pytelegrambotapi?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Как вывести лог в консоль типа (время отправки, ник пользователя, сообщение)
Вот код:

```
import telebot
import config

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN) 
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_message(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'привет': 
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'хай')
    else:

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'хз что это')


bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: `import logging`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно внутри `get_message()` выводить информацию через `print`.

В твоём случае:

```
print(f"Message from {str(message.chat.first_name)} {str(message.chat.last_name)} (id: {str(message.from.id)})")
print(f"Text: {str(message.text)}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    a = input("Bot: Для получения справки введите help или no если она вам не нужна \nUser: ")
    if a == "help":
        helpp()
    
    label .restart
    a = input("Bot: Введите имя pdf файла с расширением или опишите то что вы умеете как можно подробнее \nUser: ")
    if "pdf" in a:
        try:
            text = pdf_text(a)
        except Exception:
            print("Bot: smth went wrong")
            goto .restart
    else:
        print("Bot: Вы ввели: ", a)
        text = a
    text = cleaning(text)
    print("Bot: loading model")
    model = load_model(filename="model.pkl")
    n = int(input("Bot: Сколько вы хотите получить предсказанных компетенций: \nUser: "))
    R = make_pred(text, model, p_num=n)
    print("<========RESULT========>")
    for i in R:
        print(i)
    print("<========RESULT========>")
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_pred(words, model, p_num=1):
    if p_num==1:
        pred = model.predict([words])
        return pred
    else:
        R = []
        allpreds = model.decision_function([words]).reshape(-1)
        for i in allpreds.argsort()[-p_num:][::-1]:
            R.append(model.classes_[i])
        return R
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: И заодно поясните пожалуйста, как оба ваших ответа в этом топике отвечают на вопрос в его заголовке.