# Вывод лога в консоль в Python с PyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Надо выводить лог в консоль об времени отправки сообщения пользователем. Код:

```
import telebot
import config

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])

def get_message(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'привет': 
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'хай')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'хз что это')

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как выводить лог бота в консоль в Python с pytelegrambotapi?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1180986/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%b2-python-%d1%81-pytelegrambotapi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем случае я бы сделал `import time`, а внутри `get_message()`:

```
print(time.ctime(message.date))
```

P.S. Чтобы точнее знать, какая информация приходит к Вам вместе с сообщением, можете посмотреть данный шаблон:

```
{
 "update_id": 12345678,
 "message": {
  "message_id": 123456,
  "from": {
   "id": 123332122,  // уникальный айди пользователя
   "is_bot": false,
   "first_name": "Аноним",
   "last_name": "Анонимович",
   "username": "username", //юзернейм пользователя
   "language_code": "ru"
  },
  "chat": {
   "id": 123332122,
   "first_name": "Аноним",
   "last_name": "Анонимович",
   "username": "username",
   "type": "private"
  },
  "date": 1596019748,     //вот, откуда мы берём дату :)
  "text": "Хей, привет. Как дела?" //текст сообщения
 }
}
```